# Replace entire text with XXX using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex

How to replace entire text with XXX using RegEx in C#? it will replace number of X which equals to length of string.

for example 
original text is **Apple** replace with **XXXXX**

**Cricket** with **XXXXXX**

**Hi** with **XX**

**Outstanding** with **XXXXXXXXXXX**

```
String MyText = "Apple";
//For following line i have to written regexp to achieve 
String Output = "XXXXX"; //Apple will replace with 5 times X because Apple.length = 5
```

Comment: Make your question more clear. And did you tried _anything_?

Comment: Regex is really for pattern matching rather than simple replacement. What's wrong with `String.IndexOf` and `String.Replace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regex:

```
string s = "for example original text is Apple replace";

var replaceWord = "Apple";
var s2 = s.Replace(replaceWord , new String('X', replaceWord.Length));
```

The `new String('X', replaceWord.Length)` creates a string consisting of 'X' characters with the same length as that `replaceWord`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Regex or Replace method, instead, you can use [`Enumerable.Repeat<TResult> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899.aspx) to create an array of character `X` *(of original string length)* and then pass it to string constructor.

```
string originalStr = "Apple";    
string str = new string(Enumerable.Repeat<char>('X',originalStr.Length)
                                      .ToArray());
```

`str` will hold: `str = "XXXXX"`

**EDIT:** 
Since you need string with the same length as of original string with a single character you can use: [`String Constructor (Char, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx), which is a much better option.

```
string str3 = new string('X', originalStr.Length);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use:

```
String.Replace(word, new String('X', word.Length));
```

Comment: +1, never knew about the string constructor `string(char, int count)`